# How do I program a WPI syringe pump in PsychoPy or Python?

Tags: python, psychopy

We currently have our syringe pump programmed in E-Prime, but we are trying to move toward programming in open software. Any resources or guidance on programming the syringe pump (model below) in PsychoPy would be helpful!

Syringe pump: World Precision Instruments (WPI) SP210IW

Comment: Hi Sara, it would be worth taking this to the PsychoPy forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org People there like Richard Hochenberger have written code for other syringe systems (e.g. https://pypi.org/project/pyqmix/), but if you know the protocol via E-Prime, it _might_ be easy to implement in PsychoPy via Python code components also.

Answer (score 0):

This vendor (chemyx) offers a python solution but you have to fill out a form (which is gross).

https://www.chemyx.com/support/knowledge-base/programming-and-computer-control/python-program-for-chemyx-syringe-pumps/

Here is a github page with some python code. Start here:

https://github.com/vstadnytskyi/syringe-pump

All I did was google for "syringe pump program python".

Comment: pip install syringe-pump

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I actually "Googled" this for 2 hours trying to find information that is relevant for the instrument I am using. Every resource used a different pump which likely comes with its own particular coding based on which software is being used. 

Stay kind!
Sara

Comment: Will the github code work? It seems legit (last update 2 months ago) but I don't know enough about how pumps work to know whether it will work for you. I tried to post my solutions before my nagging;). I want to helpful not abrasive. It is unfortunate that medical solutions are so expensive and proprietary, I appreciate your efforts to find open solutions.

Comment: Try running `pip install syringe-pump` and then the code here: https://github.com/vstadnytskyi/syringe-pump/blob/master/syringe_pump/device.py
Does that connect to your device?